# Rename field name in django-filters for display

Tags: django, django-filter

Is there any way to rename the field name while displaying on django app in django-filters?
filters.py

```
import django_filters as df
from .models import Books


class BooksListFilter(df.FilterSet):
  class Meta:
    model = Books
    fields = ['name']
```

my field name in database is 'name' but i want it to display as 'BookName' in Django app. How can i achieve this?

edit: template file

```
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

{% render_table table %}


<form action="" method="get">
{% crispy filter.form filter.form.helper %}
<input type="submit" value="Filter Results"/>
</form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can define field explicitly and link field with model using [`name`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/tips.html#filter-name-and-lookup-expr-not-configured) argument:

```
class BooksListFilter(df.FilterSet):
  new_name = df.CharFilter(field_name='name')
  class Meta:
    model = Books
    fields = ['new_name']
```

Comment: btw, the docs are slightly out-of-date with the latest 2.0 release, the `name` argument should be `field_name`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i am using currently ver 1.11, its not working in it

Comment: I am getting this [invalid name] on the display field

Comment: @Aishaatique do you use template? Change name to new_name there also.

Comment: I have a template but not specifying field names explicitly there, i have added my template file

Comment: @ Aishaatique . Sorry - I was referring to django-filter 2.0, not Django 2.0.
`[invalid name]` indicates that the model field's name could not be resolved. Make sure that you use the `field_name` argument, not `name`.

Comment: TypeError: 'Meta.fields' must not contain non-model field names: new_name ???

Answer (score 5):

if u want change label , use:

```
  class BooksListFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
  name = django_filters.CharFilter(label='Book Name')
  class Meta:
    model = Books
    fields = ['name']
```

if u want to change filtered field name ( means you want to search in other field of database )

as [neverwalkaloner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/641249/neverwalkaloner) answered

```
class BooksListFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
  new_name = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='name')
  class Meta:
    model = Books
    fields = ['new_name']
```